# openpyxl '@' character inserted within formula range

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to write this formula into a cell "=SUM(A1:D1)" but after saving and opening the excel, the formula has an error and shows as: "=SUM(@A1:D1)".

The weirdest thing of all, is that the same code used to work fine. Could this be due to an update in Excel? I searched for this problem and could only find people that were having the @ inserted before the formula like: "=@SUM(..

Does anyone know what could be problem?

thanks

Comment: Excel uses the @ symbol in formulae for many different things: array formulae, data tables, etc. But it is an artefact of the GUI only and should never been entered in directly.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I'm checking the formula I'm writing with openpyxl, and it definitely doesn't have the @. Looks like Excel is somehow assuming these ranges should have the @ inserted before them.